# How to create a queue that pops its contens, item by item, with a given time interval, without halting the program?

Tags: python, timer, background, queue

I need to create a queue that pops out its items in a given time interval.
And here's the catch: this activity should run in the background, so it won't halt the program's execution until the queue is empty.
This is the how my queue looks like at the moment:

```
from collections import deque

class Queue():

    def __init__(self, sec):
        self.sec = sec
        self.q = deque()
        # start a timer that triggers
        # pop_item() every 'sec' seconds

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.q.append(item)

    def pop_item(self):
        item = self.q.popleft()
        print(item)

q1 = Queue(5)
q1.add_item('A')
q1.add_item('B')
q1.add_item('C')
```

In this example, I create a new a queue (q1) with 5 secs interval, and add 3 items.
The moment q1 is instantiated, it should start outputting its contents without halting the program every 5 seconds.
The queue is not limited to 1 instance only. There WILL be many instances, each with its own time interval for outputting its contents.

All I could accomplish is a timer that pauses the main program, so it's not what I need.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: How about a thread? Put each timer on its own thread. The main program would be on a thread and so wouldn't be paused. See the 'threading' module.

Comment: You need threading (http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) or multiprocessing (http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: If you are on a Unix-like OS, you don't need threads -- you can use [`signal.setitimer()`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#signal.setitimer).

Comment: For each Queue, you will want to start a new thread (see `threading.Thread`) that pops an item and sleeps.  Sleeping in the thread will not pause the main program.

Answer (score 1):

As the two people who commented on your question have put, the immediate response would be to use threads, just so long as when you mention that there will be many instances, the many instances is a reasonable amount. Something like the following:

```
import threading
import Queue
import time

class QueuePrinter(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, qu, *args, **kwargs):
    super(QueuePrinter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.qu = qu
  def run(self):
    while not self.qu.empty():
      item = self.qu.get()
      print item
      time.sleep(2)

qu = Queue()
printer = QueuePrinter(qu)
qu.put('String1')
qu.put('String2')
#etc...
printer.start()
qu.join()
```

You'll want to improve on that a little bit; but those are the basics for what you should stick to. Specifically you'll want to modify the run() method so that it works correctly and the get() method called on the queue within there because Queue.get is a blocking call and will wait until it can get an item.

Giving the self.qu.get(timeout=100) will throw an exception but it means that the thread won't hang until the end of time if the queue is emptied between the self.qu.empty() and the actual fetching of the item from the queue.

Comment: Thanks, I will try both your solution and Sven Marnach's (signal.setitimer()).
One more question, though. Let's assume that the printing action is performed in a global function, that the queues call. Do I need to maintain any locks, or are functions thread-safe?

Comment: What do you mean by are functions thread safe? The Queue methods are all thread-safe if that's what you're asking?